# Talend Studio - Doesn't detect Cloud artifact version change

Tags: cloud, talend

I'm facing an issue using the Talend Studio Cloud (7.3.1 Patch R2022-11), I tried publishing a new version of a Talend job that has already been pushed twice to the TMC, but this time when I try to publish this new version the studio doesn't detect the pre-existing artifact and versions.

Here some screenshots to provide a bit more context :[image: Window studio publish]

[image]

I tried publishing the artifact anyway to see, and I got some conflicts and errors on the TMC and had to use the TMC OpenAPI to delete the artifact and tasks related, but I still have the issue.

[image]

I tried restarting the studio, computer, ... :), re-sync xml poms and such but I still have the issue. Is there a solution like forcing detection or sync with the TMC in the studio or talend cloud applications ?

Sorry if there is any issue with the questions or the informations shared,

Thanks

Comment: Did you try forcing the version number of the artifact you publish ? Even if talend should auto-detect last version number, you still have the possibility to manually edit your version number.

Comment: @Corentin hi thanks for the comment, we also tried that but it created a second artifact with a the new version we entered. But last time when we tried to execute a promotion anyway it resulted with the issue I described in the post. So I am a bit reluctent as to try that again and risk another broken workspace